# How to Handle Exception in Single Method instead of handling in each method in mvc2 (.net)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I that possible to handle exception in single method for entire page or entire controllers.

here is my code

```
    public ActionResult BindProductDetails(string StartIndex, string EndIndex, string HeaderName, string SortBy, string Search, string OrderstoDisplay)
    {
        List<Products> objProduct = new List<Products>();

        try
        {
            objProduct = objProductsModel.GetProductsList(Convert.ToInt32(Session["MerchantID"]), Convert.ToInt32(StartIndex), Convert.ToInt32(EndIndex), HeaderName.Trim(), SortBy, Search, Convert.ToInt32(Session["userID"]), Convert.ToInt32(OrderstoDisplay), Session["ConnectionString"].ToString());
            ViewData["ProductCount"] = ProductsModel.ProductCount;
            ViewData["OrdersToDisplay"] = ProductsModel.OrdersToDisplay;
            CurrentProductCount = ProductsModel.CurrentCount;
            return PartialView("PVProducts", objProduct);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
           Logger.WriteToLog(objUserDetails.ErrorType, objUserDetails.MerchantName, objUserDetails.UserName, "ProductsController.BindProductDetails()", ex.Message, null, objProduct);
            return null;
        }
    }

    #region GetWarehouseDetails
    public string GetWarehouseDetails()
    {
        string strMerchantWarehouses = string.Empty;
        ProductDetails objUsersWarehouse = new ProductDetails();
        try
        {
            objUsersWarehouse = objProductsModel.GetWarehouseInfo(Convert.ToInt32(Session["MerchantID"]), Session["ConnectionString"].ToString());
            strMerchantWarehouses = json.toJshon(objUsersWarehouse);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
           Logger.WriteToLog(objUserDetails.ErrorType, objUserDetails.MerchantName, objUserDetails.UserName, "ProductsController.GetWarehouseDetails()", ex.Message, null, objUsersWarehouse);
        }
        return strMerchantWarehouses;
    }
    #endregion
```

Each and every time i am handling the exception in every method. i need alternate method,

single method handle single controller or entire application exception like (Actionfilter )for(session handling)

Answer (score 0):

You should override Applicaion_Error in Global.asax.cs as place your code in this method